# Null value for check box - Switch Statement

Tags: javascript, dom

I have basic form with input text boxes and a checkboxes. The example currently shows two items. I am trying to use a switch case to determine what was checked and then calculate a total based on the quantity and user selection. I am getting an error inside the switch case for `mufin1.checked ==  true`. How can get the proper value to be returned? [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/k9EDm/2/)

JS

```
  function charge(){
      var q_muffin1 = document.getElementById('muffin_quantity1');
      var muffin1 = document.getElementById('muffin1');
      var q_muffin2 = document.getElementById('muffin_quantity2');
      var muffin2 = document.getElementById('muffin2');
      var charge;
      var form = document.getElementById("muffinOrder");
      var checkbox = form.getElementsByTagName("checkbox");

      switch (checkbox.checked) {
          case (mufin1.checked ==  true):
          charge += q_muffin1 * muffin1;
          break;
          case (mufin2.checked ==  true):
          charge += q_muffin2 * muffin2;
          break;
        default:
          window.alert("Sorry, we are out of");
      }
      window.alert("Your total is: $" + charge);
      return false;
 }
```

html

```
<form action="" id="muffinOrder" onsubmit="return charge()">
Quantity: <input type="text" name="muffin_quantity1" id="muffin_quantity1"><input type="checkbox" name="muffin1" id="muffin1" value=".59">Blueberry Muffin .59&cent;<br />
Quantity: <input type="text" name="muffin_quantity2" id="muffin_quantity2"><input type="checkbox" name="muffin2" id="muffin2" value=".69">Banana Nutted Muffin .90&cent;<br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" >
 </form>
```

Comment: None of this makes sense. `checkbox` is a collection of elements – it’s empty, because there is no `<checkbox>` element — but it won’t have a `checked` property, and even then, it’s not one you’d want to compare against the values of other checkboxes in order… then there’s `== true`, which is redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you don't want to handle the case where both checkboxes are checked, you could write it like this :

```
switch (true) {
      case (mufin1.checked):
      charge += q_muffin1 * muffin1;
      break;
      case (mufin2.checked):
      charge += q_muffin2 * muffin2;
      break;
    default:
      window.alert("Sorry, we are out of");
  }
```

But your whole code would probably be cleaner without those variables xxx1 and xx2. I'm not sure of the whole goal but this could be something like that :

```
var charge = 0;
[1,2].forEach(function(id){
   var muffin = document.getElementById('muffin'+id);
   var q_muffin = document.getElementById('muffin_quantity'+id).value;
   if (muffin.checked) charge += q_muffin;
});
window.alert("Your total is: $" + charge);
```

Comment: +1 can you show me a snippet doing it with an array?

Comment: Ok perfect. It is showing as a result `$0[object HTMLInputElement]`. Check a live [Demo](http://holaweblearning.co.nf/php_learning/test_part1.html).

Comment: @Code_Ed_Student Added the missing `.value`

Answer (score 0):

```
string str=Convert.toString(checkbox.checked);//int return With Null Value in ""
  switch (str.toUpper()) {
          case "TRUE":
          charge += q_muffin1 * muffin1;
          break;
          case "FALSE":
          charge += q_muffin2 * muffin2;
          break;
        default:
          window.alert("Sorry, we are out of");
      }
      window.alert("Your total is: $" + charge);
```

CHECK This

Comment: Please have a look at the icons you have when you edit a question or answer, they'll help you format it correctly. But this answer is strange. What's that `Convert` ? And why do you think using strings instead of booleans would be better ?